# About 'wh + participle' and 'you guys'

Tags: grammar, participles

> we wanted to share some of what you'll see now on foursquare **while out exploring your city**.

Is the bolded text a clause with ellipsis or a participle phrase? If a phrase, is the *while* a preposition?

> You **guys** checked in 381,576,305 times in 2010

Why add *guys* ?

Comment: I think this could benefit from being posted as two separate questions.

Comment: I agree with RegDwight. The question asks about two phrases that are not related to each other; they have been read in the same place, but that is the only thing they have in common.

Comment: @RegDwight I see. I just don't want be question spammer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression can be interpreted as ellipsis or as a participial phrase, your choice.

The second expression is an informal 2nd person plural. "You guys" is a colloquial way of saying *you*. It is quite a familiar way to address a group of people, so this should never be used in a formal context.